# Add condition after place order button clicked

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, place-order

I'm new on Magento... I want to put this condition below after the user clicks on button to place an order to validate the card form just after confirm the order.

```
if (!$creditCardToken || !$senderHash) {
            $missingInfo = sprintf('Token do cartão: %s', var_export($creditCardToken, true));
            $missingInfo .= sprintf('/ Sender_hash: %s', var_export($senderHash, true));
            Mage::helper('ricardomartins_pagseguro')
                ->writeLog(
                    "Falha ao obter o token do cartao ou sender_hash.
                    Ative o modo debug e observe o console de erros do seu navegador.
                    Se esta for uma atualização via Ajax, ignore esta mensagem até a finalização do pedido.
                    $missingInfo"
                );
            Mage::throwException(
                'Falha ao processar seu pagamento. Por favor, entre em contato com nossa equipe.'
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a `sales_order_place_before` or `sales_order_place_after` observer.

If you are very new, here's how to set up an [observer](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/).

Then you want to put your code in the `Observer.php` (gonna need some tweaking)